# how to export a table to csv format and save it on specified folder

Tags: codeigniter, csv

i want to export a table to a csv file. that file should save to a folder in assets. here i am using force download.How can set path to the downloading csv file? And is there any other method to save the table as csv file to a specified folder.? pls help me ..

```
    $this->load->dbutil(); 
        $this->load->helper('file'); 

        $this->load->helper('download');
        $delimiter = ","; 
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $filename = "filename.csv";  
        $query = "SELECT * FROM cyber_details";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
        force_download($filename, $data);
```

Comment: Do you want to save CSV file on server at specific folder ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to save CSV file on server end.

you can do as following

```
    $this->load->dbutil(); 
    $this->load->helper('file'); 

    $this->load->helper('download');
    $delimiter = ","; 
    $newline = "\r\n";
    $filename = "filename.csv";  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cyber_details";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
    if ( ! write_file('./path/to/file/file_name.csv', $data))
    {
       echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else 
   {
     echo 'File written!';
   }
```

make sure the path you choose has enough permission to perform write operation.

Answer (score 1):

try this, worked for me:

```
function createcsv(){
        $this->load->dbutil();
        $this->load->helper('file');
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $delimiter = ",";
        $newline = "\r\n";
        $filename = "filename.csv";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM YourTable";
        $result = $this->db->query($query);
        $data = $this->dbutil->csv_from_result($result, $delimiter, $newline);
        force_download($filename, $data);

    }
```

Comment: it is forced download, the question is about store to folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also had come through the same issue.
Below code worked good enough for me.

```
$arry_to_csv[] = $data;
$output_file_name = 'path/to/Rejected.csv';
    $temp_memory = fopen($output_file_name, 'w');
    $csv_headers = array_keys($arry_to_csv[0]);
    $delimiter = ",";
    fputcsv($temp_memory, $csv_headers, $delimiter);
    $csv = '';
    foreach ($arry_to_csv as $line) {
        $csv.= $line['first_name'] . ',' . $line['last_name'] . "\n";
    } 
    fwrite($temp_memory, $csv);
    fclose($temp_memory);
```